# PayPal changes requiring update by January 18, 2017

Tags: paypal

After updating SSL certificates in 2016, my PHP integration of PayPal Standard has been working fine. I recently received a notice from PayPal saying, "Your integration is passing invalid or incorrect data to PayPal in one or more of your payment buttons. To ensure you can continue processing payments, please update your integration before January 18, 2017." The notice points to guidance that simply says to make sure your buttons comply with the Website Payment Integration Guide.

I can find nothing in my Pay Now button that sends data that does not meet the standards in PayPal's integration guide. I am unaware of any recent change made by PayPal that requires an "update."

Can anyone enlighten me or point me to a source of information on this January 18 "update."

Comment: Hey, I got the same message today. I don't see any issue with my code according to [their specs](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ2067&expand=true&locale=en_US). Is it just a default message they send to everyone? Were you able to resolve it? Also how the heck are we supposed to test it?

Comment: Since my post, a friend reports that PayPal support started a "ticket" from which the eventual response was that they send that message to everybody. So, apparently, when they say, "Your integration is passing invalid or incorrect data to PayPal ..." they don't really mean it. It must be wonderful to be so confident in your customers that you can treat them that way.

Comment: Man, I can't wait to leave PayPal. Really bad company that badly treats their customers/merchants. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any viable alternative to date (and they know it.) But thanks for posting!